# How to rasterise and not to get duplicate information in r

Tags: r, environment, raster, rasterize

I'm having trouble rasterizing a data.frame using the raster package in R.

My data.frame contains environmental data for the world oceans (temperature etc.) with their coordinates (grid 0.5*0.5), decimal longitude from -90 to 90 and decimal latitude from -180 to 180. So the base contains 90*2*2 x 180*2*2 = 360*720 = 259200 rows, and 59 colones (57 variables + 2 colones of coordinates).

After rasterizing, this is what I get with `plot(r)`: http://postimg.org/image/rqocxcbi3/

So, a duplicate image, in the wrong direction.

My code is:

```
FILE_ENV = read.csv('ENV_DATABASE.csv')
coordinates(FILE_ENV) <- ~LON+LAT
proj4string(FILE_ENV3)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
FILE_ENV = spTransform(FILE_ENV,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
gridded(FILE_ENV) = TRUE
r = raster(FILE_ENV)

plot(r)
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing/screwing up here?

Thanks

Edit :
`head(FILE_ENV)`

> LON   LAT  BAT BAT_CLASSE      SLOPE SEDIMENT SST SST_SEAFLOOR SST_SUM SST_WIN SAL_SURF SAL_SEAFLOOR...
>
> 1 -179.75 89.75 2804         NA 0.14031838       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA
>
> 2 -179.25 89.75 2941         NA 0.12495525       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA
>
> 3 -178.75 89.75 3048         NA 0.07784129       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA
>
> 4 -178.25 89.75 3093         NA 0.03123910       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA
>
> 5 -177.75 89.75 3109         NA 0.01536359       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA
>
> 6 -177.25 89.75 3063         NA 0.15619729       NA  NA           NA      NA      NA       NA           NA

Comment: Sounds like you need a transpose in there somewhere, I don't know if the standard `t()` works on raster objects, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but I still get a duplicated plot..

Comment: `spTransform` is for doing coordinate transformations -- you don't need that. My guess is that the `raster` constructor does not understand coordinates of your FILE_ENV object. Break it down into more explicit pieces for `raster`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not show `head(FILE_ENV)` (`d` in my code) it hard to say how exactly you should to this. But in essence you should be able to do something like the below:

```
library(raster)
d <- read.csv('ENV_DATABASE.csv')
r <- rasterFromXYZ(d, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my first message to add `head(FILE_ENV)`. The result improved with your code but I still get the same problem (duplicated and rotated image) : http://s27.postimg.org/6krcblg43/Rplot2.png

Comment: I totally recreated the coordinates colones of my database and it works now ; I still don't know where the problem came from but it was obviously in the database

Answer (score 0):

I would think rasterfromXYZ would have worked. That said, it seems like it works best when working with `raster` to break things down into smaller, more explicit chunks. It seems that the constructor is assuming you want something different out of your object and it's losing the coordinates for your matrix entries.

This isn't the best practice but since you know your data is a strict grid we can turn the entries into points and then rasterize them:

```
library(raster)
coords <- coordinates(FILE_ENV[,c("LON","LAT")])
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,data=FILE_ENV)
r <- rasterize(spdf,field='value',raster(nrow=360,ncol=720))
```

Now r should contain your raster.